# WordPress custom post type category link

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type ***videoCourse*** that inherit the default categories
i am looking for a way to list all my categories with link to each a page that list posts of a specific category,
Example: 
Categoriy named "Sciences" the link `videoCourses/Sciences`

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

```
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
```

Comment: Not exactly, i want to generate the category link relative to the custom post type
something like ==> videoCourses/Sciences

Comment: maybe: `$cat = get_category ($cat); 'videoCourses/'.$cat->slug;` ?

You can also use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/
or check out the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

I got here Googling, so to help anyone else landing here…

When working with custom post types you'll probably have to use `get_terms` or `get_the_terms` instead of `get_category` etc.

See codex here: [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) / [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) (looking at the code snippets at the bottom of those pages should help).

So you could use something like this (copied from `get_terms` page) to list all the terms with link to term archive, separated by an interpunct (·):

```
<?php

$args = array( 'hide_empty=0' );

$terms = get_terms( 'my_term', $args );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
}

?>
```